# Regex for a string that contains anything but consecutive spaces

Tags: regex

I think it's easiest to start off with an example line

`3432543       name that % might 7 include pretty . much 433 anything       545231       4522`

I'm looking for an expression that matches the `name that % might 7 include pretty . much 433 anything` portion so that it includes everything until it encounters 2 spaces, and will not match if it had to include 2 or more spaces.
So for example I want this pattern

`^\d+ +(pattern) +\d+$`

to end up not matching, and not ending up including the        `545231` as part of the name.
Please keep in mind that this is just a simple example to illustrate the problem, it will be included in much more complex expressions matching more complex strings.

Comment: Trim your string and split it on two or more spaces.

Comment: That would make parsing the string in question an even more horrendous task than it already is, since it can come in dozens of different variations which all look similar but often have different meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match substring that is only single space separated:

```sh
\S+(?:\s\S+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9DjNrt/2)

This match will start with 1+ non-whitespace text followed 0+ of such words separated by a single space only.

For your desired pattern match use:

```
^\d+\s+\S+(?:\s\S+)*\s+\d+$
```

Comment: That looks like a good start. But it must also allow a string without any spaces at all. If i put it into my example above ```^\d+ +\S+(?:\s\S+)+ +\d+$```, it does indeed not match my example string, but it also doesn't match ```3432543       name_without_space         4522``` which it should. It does match ```3432543       name with space        4522``` as desired though. Maybe i could simply expand it like this? ```(\S+|\S+(?:\s\S+)+)``` That seems to work for this case...

Comment: It is because your pattern is not correct. Use `^\d+\s+\S+(?:\s\S+)*\s+\d+$`

Comment: So, ```\S+(?:\s\S+)*``` instead of the ```\S+(?:\s\S+)+``` from your answer? Seems to work on first glance. Can you edit your answer? I'll do some further tests later and see if i can find some some problem case.

Comment: yes it is updated